# the onDismissed property makes my ListView crash when a method is called

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, listtile, dismissible

I got a red error screen when I get to the view of my ListView. It looks like the problem comes from the "onDismissed" property.

Below is my ListView code and the i'll also include the "deleteRival" method that is called during the onDismissed

```
ListView(
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        children: snapshot.data!.map((rival){
                                          return Center(
                                            child: Card(
                                              child: Material(
                                                elevation: 10.0,
                                                child: Dismissible(
                                                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                                                  key: ObjectKey(rival),
                                                  onDismissed: deleteRival(rival.idRival), // <------- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                                                  background: buildSwipeActionRight(),
                                                  child: ListTile(
                                                    tileColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                                    title: Text(
                                                      rival.nameRival,
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                      style: const  TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      );
```

This is my "deleteRival" method:

```
deleteRival(rivalId) async{
  final statAccess = DatabaseModel();
  await statAccess.deleteRival(rivalId).then((value){
    if (value == 1){
      alertDialog("Suppression réussie", true);
    }else{
      alertDialog("Suppresion échouée", false);
    }

  });

}
```

[image: The crash I have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of method `deleteRival` is `Future<dynamic> Function(dynamic)` and the expected method type by the `onDismissed` is `void Function(DismissDirection)?`, this is why you get this error.

Just replace `onDismissed: deleteRival(rival.idRival),` with  `onDismissed: (_) => deleteRival(rival.idRival),`